# referencing the current user in a page i created in wordpress

Tags: functions, users

I created a page in wordpress and i tried to access the current logged in user via wp_get_current_user() and am getting error "function undefined". please how do I make this function available in my page.

Comment: is this a php page you created?

Comment: Yes it is a php page

Comment: try adding `require('/the/path/to/your/wp-blog-header.php');` at the top of your PHP page

Comment: thanks Bainternet but I have added the require and am getting the error "cannot coonect to database" this is the code below:

Comment: <?php require('/wordpress/wp-blog-header.php');
  
  $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
   
   $current_user->set_role(rocky2);

?>

Comment: what are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

You can use following..

```
global $current_user;
get_currentuserinfo();
```

Than you can access everything as

```
$current_user->user_login,$current_user->user_email...
```

Here is explanation...
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_currentuserinfo